# how to identify source of frequent process startup

Tags: python, linux, django, process, startup

Some months ago I used to play around with Python and Django, finally setting up a Django web service running `python manage.py ...` on a RaspberryPi. Now, I'd like to use the Linux device for other things. Unfortunately, there seems to be a frequent startup of some process (every couple of seconds) that eats up the available processing power. And I can not remember or see, WHO is starting this process or WHERE it is started.

The following picture shows a `htop` output. The process shown right below the title row uses **83%** of CPU power and seems to be invoked by the following command line (`run_gunicorn` seems to be part of the Python / Django environment):
`/home/pi/.virtualenvs/ENV_python27/bin/python /home/pi/examples/django__test/manage.py run_gunicorn -w 4` .

[image: htop output]

The fact that the PID of the odd process changes every couple of seconds makes it impossible for me as a linux novice to further invest its source and details. In the picture the process has the PID 24296.

**Is there a way to find the place within the linux file system and its files where this process is frequently started? Can I somehow remove the respective command in order to not waste so much processing power? Are there a handful of possible places from where Linux can startup processes automatically (like CRON, which I have already checked)?**

Please ask for more details and I will try to provide them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gunicorn process is probably being run by supervisor. Look at your `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` file or `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf.d` directory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. By issuing ``/etc/supervisor $ cat supervisord.conf`` I don't see anything that could hint any relationship to the process stealing my processing power. Any other suggestions?
**EDIT**: Sorry, the conf file includes another file from the subfolder ``conf.d`` . There I see the call. Will try to neutralize it.